# Can DNS host records be setup to create wildcard sub-subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain

Is it possible to create a wildcard host record for a sub-subdomain ie *.foo.example.com?

Comment: Yes! . (15 min)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, in the general case.  DNS supports this, bind zonefiles support this.  If you're using a management UI, you'll need to check what's supported by that.

```
@ORIGIN example.com.
; ...
*.foo  IN A  192.0.2.1
```

Note that if you create another record for an item in foo, then that will stop the wildcard from providing a record.  Wildcards only match where no other name matches.  So you'll need to explicitly provide the data that the wildcard would have provided.

```
@ORIGIN example.com.
; ...
*.foo       IN A    192.0.2.1
fred.foo    IN TXT  "Fred was here"
fred.foo    IN A    192.0.2.1
```

Comment: Thanks - that is helpful.  Not sure if my registrar supports this through its UI.

Comment: If your registrar is serving your DNS records, you can call them and ask them to help you set it up.

Comment: let's hope so  !